# Is it possible to earn Mega-Tickets without spending real money?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

The latest update (1.1.3.1323, 3 september) for Adventure Capitalist adds Mega-Tickets, which cost both Mega-Bucks and Gold Bars.

[image: picture of mega tickets purchasing screen]

I know that Mega-Bucks are earned through regular gameplay and that Gold Bars are available as an in app purchase. Is there any way to earn Gold Bars (and therefore the Mega-Tickets) through gameplay?

Comment: Before this new patch it wasn't. Probably it still isn't.

Comment: @Mathias711 that's disappointing, especially given how much the mega tickets were hyped in the release notes for this version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can either buy them with Mega Bucks OR Gold bars ;)

Comment: ^ this. You *do not* need to pay both costs. Just one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikia](http://adventure-capitalist.wikia.com/wiki/Gold) it isn't obtainable through gameplay, and I never encountered it anywhere, so I guess they are right.

> Gold is the real-money currency in AdVenture Capitalist, and cannot be obtained through gameplay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can earn Gold Bars through the gameplay, especially when playing the event games (such as *Insert Coins to Continue*). The gold is awarded when you reach certain number of upgrades. Gold also can be earned by *Daily Deals*, *Daily Rewards* and *Spin* wheel. In this way I've managed to collect over 240 through the gameplay within few days in order to buy *Greet Suit* (I was lucky enough to win 100 of gold bars in spin wheel).